# How to print fatal error in code editor?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, callback

i have make an php editor with so much effort but i cant print the fatal error. and want to print the fatal error. How to do this.
I have code for run the php through eval function

here is my jsfiddle - `**`http://jsfiddle.net/3c7F6/3/`**`
I want to print an fatal error. Please help me to do this.please check the code and give me the suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost did the job: you already added a function `error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError,err,textStatus)` in your code.

All you have to do is replacing the `alert()` by adding something like

```
$(form).children('.stdout').html("Fatal error").removeClass('hidden');
```

Answer (score 2):

What if you use

```
display_errors("1");
```

Comment: I had tried but not working. When fatal error generated output is not recieved in jsonp format so i cant print it but when output is corectly generated like parse error or no any error genaratd then output is in jsonp format